# Selecteting element if previous TD with CSS

Tags: css

If have the following HTML (there could be more TDs), can I select ALL `<div>`s with style **divE** in all `TD`s before the one with id="current"?

I think i can do it with jQuery, but can this be done with pure CSS?

HTML

```
<table id="myTbl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="red">asdasd</div>
          <div class="divE"></div>
          <div class="divE"></div>
          content
        </td>
        <td id="current">
          <div class="red">asdasd</div>
          <div class="divE"></div>
          <div class="divE"></div>
          content
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="red">asdasd</div>
          <div class="divE"></div>
          <div class="divE"></div>
          content
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *before* selector, but what you can do is select all `td`s (that aren't `#current`), and then "reset" (or "undo") the styles on all the `td`s after `#current`.

```css
td:not(#current) div.divE{
    /* Styles for <td>s before "#current" */
}
td#current ~ td div.divE{ /* This means all "td div.divE" after "td#current" */
    /* Reset/undo styles for all other <td>s */
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/MYhPP/2/